# How can I prevent Joda Time throwing an exception during Brazilian DST transition period

Tags: java, jodatime

Today our Brazilian users are generating plenty of crash reports for us. I've tracked it down to this code, which throws a Joda exception:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // force Joda to act like we are in Sao Paolo on 2015-10-18
        DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(1445185758078L); // 2015-10-18T18:29
        DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo"));

        // most of users have offset == 0, but it could be any number of millis from 0 to 86_400_000-1 (millis in day) 
        int offset = 0;

        // local time at start of day + offset millis  
        final LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay(offset);

        // convert to a time on the current day
        DateTime dateTime = localTime.toDateTimeToday();  // throws org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException exception
        System.out.println("dateTime = " + dateTime);
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 0 for hourOfDay is not supported: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 2015-10-18T00:29:18.078 (America/Sao_Paulo)
    at org.joda.time.chrono.ZonedChronology$ZonedDateTimeField.set(ZonedChronology.java:486)
    at org.joda.time.chrono.BaseChronology.set(BaseChronology.java:240)
    at org.joda.time.LocalTime.toDateTimeToday(LocalTime.java:1287)
    at org.joda.time.LocalTime.toDateTimeToday(LocalTime.java:1270)
```

I'm using Java 1.8.0_60 on OS X 10.11 with Joda Time 2.8.2.

What work-around will allow me to correctly get a DateTime instance representing a time on the current day that is *offset* milliseconds after the start of the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't go though a LocalTime. Create a DateTime, and add the offset in milliseconds:

```
DateTime startOfDay = LocalDate.now().toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime dateTime = startOfDay.plus(offset);

System.out.println("dateTime = " + dateTime);
```